# Websites can't seem to access Flash Local Storage

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, chromium

There is an educational website my kid uses for school which requires flash. During the login process I am directed to click "Allow Local Storage"(this is the website's button, not adobe's popup), which I assume directs the browser(or plugin) to store information on my hard drive.

Now, the problem is that after having the website store(or attempt to store) the flash data on my hard drive, nothing happens. There is no popup asking my permission if I will allow that particular website access to my local data storage. I checked the local data storage permissions through the macromedia web address and websites are allowed to store data. In fact, I checked my hidden .macromedia folder in my home folder and there is in fact a folder being created there with the name of the website I am trying to use. This folder is being created when I click on the educational website's "Allow Local Storage" button.

I've tried both chromium and firefox. I've changed the browser settings to allow all storage; I've checked the permissions on the .macromedia folder and ensured I am the owner; I can see that a folder with the website's name is being created inside the .macromedia folder when attempting to use Flash's Local Data Storage; I've verified that global settings do indeed allow for Local Data Storage.

I am not willing to install google chrome. I could very much use some suggestions, I am not very familiar with linux so please give me your instructions in "Barney Style".

Ubuntu 12.04.3 All updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the preferences using `flash-player-properties`.
1. Open Adobe Flash Player preferences (either by searching in dash or by running `flash-player-properties`).
2. Go to *Storage* and select **allow sites to store information on this computer**.
3. You can also modify **Local Storage Settings by Site**.

[image: flash]

Comment: Is flash-player-properties included as part of a default install from the ubuntu software center? I don't think it is as I could not find it. Anyway, to try your suggestion I removed the ubuntu flash install and manually installed the flash plugin and flash-player-properties which I obtained directly from Adobe's website. Regretfully, your suggestion had no impact on my current dilemma. Because I absolutely needed this website to work, I installed google chrome (Something I really didn't want to do) and everything works perfectly inside that browser. I still want a solution that works with FF.